# React Bootstrap's <Col align='center'>...</Col> gives ts2322 warning with typescript

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-bootstrap

I have the following code in my React app.
Where `Col` is imported from [React-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/layout/grid/)

```js
  <Col md={5} align="center">
           This is a column
  </Col>
```

For the above code, Typescript gives me the following warning:

[image]

A similar thing happens with the ul tag's type attribute

[image]

I am using strict mode in Typescript.
Though this warning does not stop my compilation but how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I think the attribute `align="center"` for Col on React Bootstrap doesn't exists.

Put the `className="align-items-center"` instead or `className="text-center"` and see if that works for you.

Comment: Hey thanks, className `text-center` works for me, but I have a similar problem for the ul HTML tag with its type attribute. Please check the question (I have updated it just now)

Comment: Hi there. The tag ul doesn't support the **type** attribute. Try changing the <ul> for <ol>, because it has the type attribute and can receive the values: `1, A, a, I, i`. I've made a codepen to exemplify it: https://codepen.io/grazielle-carvalho/pen/wvzgBPj

Comment: But I want to use type='square', how can I do that?

Comment: You can achieve that with CSS `list-style: square`.